# Confused by use of = in block

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

```
void (^configureCell)(PhotoCell*, Photo*) = ^(PhotoCell* cell, Photo* photo) {
    cell.label.text = photo.name;
};
```

I never have seen before the "=" sign in a block, how does is work?

Thanks!

Comment: Your title is extremely lacking in descriptiveness.

Comment: If I know how to describe this block, I would not be asking this now, would I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a block declaration which is assigned to the configureCell variable.

This is block variable definition (like i.e. NSArray *array):

```
void (^configureCell)(PhotoCell *, Photo *)
```

This is block definition:

```
^(PhotoCell* cell, Photo* photo) {...}
```

You can use this block like this:

```
PhotoCell *cell = [PhotoCell ...];
Photo *photo = [Photo ...];

// Execute block
configureCell(cell, photo);
```

Answer (score 4):

if your referring to this bit

`void (^configureCell)(PhotoCell*, Photo*) = ^(PhotoCell* cell, Photo* photo) {`

this is assigning the block to a variable named: `configureCell`.

I suggest you look at http://www.fuckingblocksyntax.com

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [the `Apple Documentation`](http://bit.ly/stackBlockExplanation).
If you write code blocks like this you can call methods like you would do it in `Java` for example.

so you could pass variables through like:

```
MyCustomCell *cell = configureCell(photoCellVariable, photoVariable);
```

instead of calling it like a message, like you normally do it in `Objective-C`

```
MyCustomCell *cell = [ConfigurePhotoCell:photoCellVariable 
                        andPhotoVariable:photoVariable];
```